# Conditional Field Selection

Tags: mysql

I have data like this

```
id | bookDate   | regisDate  | payDate    | status  
1  | 2001-12-31 | 2002-12-31 | 2003-12-31 | 1  
2  | 2001-12-31 | 2002-12-31 | 2003-12-31 | 2  
3  | 2001-12-31 | 2002-12-31 | 2003-12-31 | 3
```

and i want the result is like this

```
id | date | status 
x  | x    | x
```

notice `date` field is reduced from 3 into 1 field. and the conditional is like this. if the status is `1` then take `date` from `bookDate`, if `2` take from `regisDate`, if `3` take from `payDate`

example for data with id `1`, then the result of query will be like this

```
id | date       | status 
1  | 2001-12-31 | 1
```

it is possible do that in MySQL query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `case` statements in MySQL.

```
SELECT id,
 CASE status
  WHEN 1 THEN bookDate
  WHEN 2 THEN regisDate
  WHEN 3 THEN payDate
 END
 AS date,
 status
 FROM table
```

Comment: Thank you marcus. This really mean a lot for me. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT id,
    CASE status
    WHEN 1 THEN bookDate
    WHEN 2 THEN regisDate
    WHEN 3 THEN payDate END as Date,
    Status
FROM YourTable;
```